# Rails will not set sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a login form that is supposed to create a session upon submission of correct credentials, however the sessions are not saving. What is causing this?

sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/posts'
    else
      session[:id] = nil
      flash[:warning] = "Failed login- try again"
      redirect_to '/login'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil 
    redirect_to login_path 
  end
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateSessions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :sessions do |t|

      t.integer :session_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What problem you are facing you are using the right syntax please specify the error or used the debugger for debugg your application

Comment: Please show the log file entries for the login attempt and the following redirect. How did you configure Rails to store the session? How do you know the session is not saved? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you are using activerecord-session_store gem for storing sessions in a table.

add this in initializers/session_store.rb

```
require "action_dispatch/session/active_record_store"

Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => 
 '_lotuspay_session'
```

Comment: i am not using it

Comment: then you must use this gem https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store, It will allow you to  save session in a table